# Pug - Submenu Toggling

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

I'm trying to style a side navigation menu in a pug file in a bootstrap based web app. My goal is to be able to toggle only a single sub-menu as active at a time.

Here's my pug partial page:

```
.sidebar
   li.item(id="reportsmenu")
    a(class="dropdown" data-toggle="show" aria-expanded="false" href="#reportsmenu") Reports
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/reports/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/reports/add') Add Reports
      li.item
       a(href='/reports/manage') Manage Reports       
   li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Video
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/video/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/video/live') Live Video
      li.item
       a(href='/video/saved') Saved Video
   li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Automation
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/automation/overview') Overview
   li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Notifications
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/notifications/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/notifications/add') Add Notifications
      li.item
       a(href='/notifications/edit') Edit Notifications   
   li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Locations
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/locations/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/locations/add') Add Location
      li.item
       a(href='/locations/edit') Manage Location
      li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Equipment
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/equipment/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/equipment/add') Add Equipment
      li.item
       a(href='/equipment/edit') Manage Equipment
   li.item
    a(class="dropdown-toggle" href="#") Users
    ul.submenu
      li.item
       a(href='/users/overview') Overview
      li.item
       a(href='/users/add') Add Users
      li.item
       a(href='/users/edit') Manage Users   
   li.item
    a(href='/account') My Account
   li.item
    a(href='/settings') Settings
   li.item
    a(href='/help') Help
```

So far I have tried including a javascript file to toggle an extra `.active` class on just the first `ul` as a test, which seemed to do nothing from within my main layout, which the sidebar is included within. Also have poured over various tutorials, but translating alot of them to the pug format has been somewhat frustrating.

Here is the main layout:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Company Site
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
    script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
    script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
    script(src='/js/main.js')
  body
    nav.navbar.navbar-inverse
      .navbar-container
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          a.navbar-brand(href='/') Company
        #navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse

          ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            if user
              li
                a(href='/users/logout') Logout 
            else
              li
                a(href='/users/register') Register
              li
                a(href='/users/login') Login
    .sidebar-container
      include partials/sidebar
    .content-container
      != messages('message', locals)
      if errors
        each error, i in errors
          div(class='alert alert-danger') #{error.msg}
      block content
        br
        hr
    footer
      p &copy; 2019 Company, Inc
```

So far, the only thing that happens when I load up my index page, the sidebar appears, and each of the parent items in the sidebar are clickable. And the `Reports` section can be clicked once, then on a second click it just disappears.

Any pointers on where to go here would be super appreciated! Let me know if having the CSS would help as well.

Comment: There are a few html to pug conversion tools online, they are really helpful when you need to convert a lot of code at once such as from a tutorial.

Comment: FWIW, it was just after the point where I started writing this type of code that I decided to move over to vue.js and vue-router to handle this sort of thing in our app.

Comment: Originally looked at vue for this project, and since I'm not a web eng/designer by trade, this seemed like a quicker trade off. Pug is proving to be an annoyance though. Kind of wishing I'd gone with ejs instead

Comment: Moving from pug to EJS trades one set of annoyances for another.  When you use pug as a simple templating engine it's great for quickly authoring HTML code.  Many large production sites use pug, many use EJS.

Comment: I should also mention that we use pug to render our Vue.js pages.  They work incredibly well together.